# Как лучше отредактировать SVG графический файл? CorelDRAW портит изображение

Tags: svg

Редактирую SVG изображение в CorelDRAW и портится прозрачность, тональность. Мне нужно всего лишь сдвинуть несколько элементов, поменять их координаты. Пример кода элемента: `<path d="M324.006 104.756H268.107V27H282.875V90.8552H313.833V27H328.601V90.8552H338.337V123H324.006V104.756Z" fill="#F9F9F9"/>` Какие здесь параметры необходимо поменять для того что бы весь элемент сместился влево на 100 пикселей

Comment: добавьте атрибут `transfrom='translate(-100,0)'`

Answer (score 1):

Так может быть ?

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="250 12 104 123" width="100">
  <path d="M324.006 104.756H268.107V27H282.875V90.8552H313.833V27H328.601V90.8552H338.337V123H324.006V104.756Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```